# PHP 8 digit number question

Tags: php

How to make a number 8 digit as standard digit. The number will be get to a user id from database.
Example

```
user_id = 1 // This should should be echo as 00000001
user_id = 11 // This should should be echo as 00000011
user_id = 111 // This should should be echo as 00000111
```

How can I code this? Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` function with `%08s` as the format string:

```
printf("%08s",$user_id);
```

If you want to store the result back in the string you can use `sprintf` as:

```
$user_id = sprintf("%08s",$user_id);
```

The format specifier `%08s` says:

```
s : Interpret the argument as a string
8 : Print the string left justified within 8 alloted places
0 : Fill the unused places with 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`printf`](http://php.net/printf):

```
printf("%08d", $user_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has `sprintf`:

```
$user_str = sprintf("%08d", $user_id);
echo $user_str;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

```
   echo str_pad($user_id,8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

$user_id = str_pad($user_id, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

Answer (score 0):

```
function leadingZeroes($number, $paddingPlaces = 3) {
    return sprintf('%0' . $paddingPlaces . 'd', $number);
}
```

[Source](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/blog/2010/03/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeroes-in-php/).